# Cannot convert ipython notebook to pdf

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, ipython, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm running into an error during conversion from Jupyter Notebook to PDF:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed
```

Then I tried running the pdf-converter from the command line and received the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.291 ... Till att börja med har vi \$\frac{1}{2}

?
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text>
                $
l.291 ... Till att börja med har vi \$\frac{1}{2}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I then get a line of exceptions ending with:

```
OSError: PDF creating failed
```

I have looked through the document and I found no unmatched `$` anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter converts a notebook to PDF by first converting it to LaTeX, and then using your local latex to convert it to pdf. You get this error because there is an unmatched `$` sign in the LaTeX document `nbconvert` creates, and the error message you see is actually latex failing because of it.

You could try converting the document in two steps. First run

```
jupyter nbconvert thenotebook.ipynb --to latex
```

Then examine the LaTeX file around line 291 to see if there is indeed an unmatched `$`. My guess is you will find one. When you found and corrected it, you can do the second step and convert it to pdf with `latex`:

```
latex thenotebook.tex
```

If you cannot find the `$` symbol in the LaTeX document, you should expand the question with the lines surrounding line 291 so that we can help.

Comment: You where sort of correct. When I looked in my notebook there where no unmatched `$` but when I converted it into latex, jupyter aparently decided to insert `\\` in front of every dollar sign making them to actual dollar-signs and not the dollar-sign that latex recognizes

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve an issue with spaces in image names in my LaTeX document preventing export to PDF. Thanks!