# Problem with converting a Jupyter Notebook to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, type-conversion, jupyter

I'm trying to convert a jupyter notebook to pdf. I'm really new to jupyter, python, and programming in general, so I don't really understand any lines of the error precisely, but for what I can understand there is a problem with a .py document I am importing to the jupyter notebook. The .py document just has three lists, and that's it. I named it 'lists' and it is on the same folder as my jupyter notebook, so when I use 'run lists.py' it works perfectly fine for the rest of the code.

Another thing is that I go straight to the file menu in jupyter notebook > download as > PDF via LaTex (.pdf)
So I don't know how I can actually convert something with code directly.

really appreciate the help.

I tried searching in google similar problems but it seems I haven't found one that has the same error as mine.

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) 
(preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.2a <2019/01/15> (tvz))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
No file notebook.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ppl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ppl.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlzplm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omszplm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxzplm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1zplm.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ppl.fd)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.349 run 2019_
               lists
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.349 run 2019_
               lists.py
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Comment: take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121822/missing-inserted-error-message-when-converting-jupyter-notebook-to-pdf-with). looks to be the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear 
Is the question regarding input of file or exporting as a pdf

Assuming exporting the notebook
You can simply press ctrl + P that will open the print document window, in the print window print it as a PDF or save to any other file formats like .py

Comment: Hi, well, the question is about exporting it as PDF. I can do that but the format isn't quite right that way, it just takes the document like a print screen rather than a converted format that looks better, and I want to understand how to correct it so that I can continue converting other documents as PDF with LaTex, which converts it in a 'pretty' way so to speak.